# Ruby File download

Tags: ruby, curl, cucumber, nokogiri, mechanize

[image]

Is there a way of accessing this dialog box to get the file name or to save this file somewhere so i can access it later. I am using Ruby mechanize to navigate through the website to get to this screen.

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is using TAB and ENTER (win32ole ) in order to download it..

Comment: Sorry i'm new to Ruby, would i be able to put this into my script and tell it to download automatically

Comment: Yep all you need is to require 'win32ole' at the top of your script..See solution below

Comment: I was confused, I didn't understand that Mechanize was a Gem, Why you tagged this post with Nokogiri?

Comment: I tagged Nokogiri because it is built in to mechanize and you use it along with mechanize. You navigate through the website to the page you want to be at then you use nokogiri to extract the url of the file and then you use curb to download the file.

Comment: That comment made sense until you mentioned curb. Why wouldn't you use mechanize to download the file?

Comment: I just seen somewhere that curb was better at downloading files than mechanize.

Answer (score 4):

There is no dialog with mechanize. You submit the form, that returns a Mechanize::File object, and you can then save that like so:

```
file = form.submit
File.open('myfile','w'){|f| f << file.body}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

Use nokogiri to open the page:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

go through the doc page and find that link for download.
then you can use something link this:

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start('theserver.com') { |http| 
   resp = http.get('/xx/the_file_to_downlaod.csv')
      open('the_downlaod.csv', 'wb') { |file|
         file.write(resp.body)
      }
}
```

Comment: If i type this into my script ["@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))"]
it will open the url of the download/save dialog box?

Comment: I don't think so, that is done by the browser. Nokogiri is for pasing a web not for downloading, you can use http.get(xxx) for download it

Comment: I just dont see how once i click the submit button on the form with the ruby script that i can then access the file from the dialog box that shows up. If i use "@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) i would need the url of the dialog box which i dont have. I just have the url of the form that i clicked the submit on.

Comment: The way I suggested does not simulate click, just finds and follows the urls. If you want to simulate the click then, I guess you should follow the suggestion of  @Xwris Stoixeia

Comment: It won't work. You describe an over-complicated way to do a GET request. OP is posting to a form.

Comment: this post was tagged with nokogiri that is why I suggested nokogiri. I don't know mechanize (yet)